# Installation of luasocket using luarocks

Tags: lua, luasocket, luarocks

I installed luarocks in my windows xp(32 bit) system following instructions available on

http://luarocks.org/en/Installation_instructions_for_Windows

to install luasocket from luarocks I used command **"luarocks install luasocket"** in command prompt. but ended up eith an error:

```
**Warning: Failed searching manifest: Failed loading manifest: Failed fetching man
ifest for http://luarocks.org/repositories/rocks - Error fetching file: Failed d
ownloading http://luarocks.org/repositories/rocks/manifest
Error: No results matching query were found.**
```

so it was not able to find out luasocket.rock file. I downloaded file **luasocket-2.0.2-5.src.rock** from link :

http://luarocks.org/repositories/rocks/

Now I tried to install this .rock file using command **luarocks install luarocks install "C
:\Documents and Settings\Ankur_Gupta37\Desktop\LuaRocks\2.1\lua\luarocks"**

(I put **luasocket-2.0.2-5.src.rock** at location "C
:\Documents and Settings\Ankur_Gupta37\Desktop\LuaRocks\2.1\lua\luarocks\luasocket-2.0.2-5.src.rock")

but again ended up with an error :

```
**set INCLUDE=C:/Documents and Settings/Ankur_Gupta37/Desktop/LuaRocks/2.1/include
;%INCLUDE% &set LIB=C:/Documents and Settings/Ankur_Gupta37/Desktop/LuaRocks/2.1
;%LIB% &msbuild /p:"VCBuildAdditionalOptions= /useenv" luasocket.sln &mkdir mime
 & mkdir socket &cp src/mime.dll mime/core.dll &cp src/socket.dll socket/core.dl
l
'msbuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
cp: cannot stat `src/mime.dll': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `src/socket.dll': No such file or directory
Error: Build error: Failed building.**
```

any body tell me the problem and its solution..

Answer (score 8):

You could try install latest version from git.
Current status is 3.0 rc1.
This version compatible with Lua 5.1/5.2
e.g.

```
luarocks install https://raw.github.com/diegonehab/luasocket/master/luasocket-scm-0.rockspec
```

or

```
luarocks install luasocket --only-server=http://luarocks.org/repositories/rocks-scm
```

This rockspec works with gcc (MinGW) and with MSVC.
If you use MSVC you should run luarocks form `Visual Studio Command Prompt`
if you use MinGW then you should add path to `mingw32-gcc` in to %PATH% environment variable.

Comment: of course you need C compiler. You can check [MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw). It has windows installer.

Comment: Had same problem but on Linux, this solved it, had a feeling it was due to version.

Comment: I just did this by using the Visual Studio Command Prompt, but I had to open it with admin rights and then navigate back to the Visual Studio Command Prompt folder (...\Microsoft Visual Studio 1X.0) in order to successfully run the `luarocks install luasocket` command.